# Algebraic manipulation question coming from Method of Moments application

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

So today in my statistical inference class the professor wrote on the board:

Using the Method of Moments:

$$\sigma^2 = E[Y_1^2|\theta] - E[Y_1|\theta]^2$$
$$= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j^2} - \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j}\right)^2$$
$$= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2 }$$

where $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}Y_j$(average values of Y's)

**I am confused at how he arrived at the last equation from the one above that and I've been trying to figure it out.**

Here's what I have so far:

$$= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j^2} - \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j}\right)^2$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\left(n\bar Y\right)^2$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{Y_j^2} - \bar Y^2$$

Which is fundamentally different that the equation that my professor had on the board. My equation takes the difference of squares while his takes the square of a difference and then sums those up...

Where did I go so wrong? Is there just some statistical insight that I don't know and haven't used?

Comment: they are equal and to verify it, you need to expand it. For example:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(a-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(b-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} - \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 $$

Comment: @dezdichado I see that by your example, they would be equal for $\sum Y = a + b$. But how do go about justifying it for the case where the summation is $n$ terms. What makes me really uneasy here is that from high school I've been taught that $(a - b)^2 \neq a^2 - b^s$ because there's a middle term on the left hand side($-2ab$)

Comment: I suggest  you grab a pen and paper to try and work it out instead of just staring. It really is not difficult and requires no more than an 9th grader's knowledge of algebra about opening brackets.

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j$?

Comment: @user408858 thanks for the correction! Just forgot the fraction in front :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's easier to go the other way around. Let $S^2$ be the sample variance and note

\begin{align*}
S^2 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j-\bar Y)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j^2-2\bar Y Y_j + \bar Y^2)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2-2\bar Y \left(\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j\right) + n\bar Y^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2-2\bar Y (n \bar Y) + n\bar Y^2\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 - \bar Y^2.
\end{align*}

Essentially the Method of Moments here is suggesting to estimate $\sigma^2$ by $S^2$, where the two population moments $E(Y_1^2|\theta),E(Y_1|\theta)$ are replaced by the corresponding sample moments.

Comment: I am so sorry but I still don't understand. (Really not trying to be difficult!!) How did you make the 2nd to last equation equal to the last equation? 
Wouldn't $-2 \bar Y (n \bar Y) + n \bar Y^2 = -n\bar Y^2$?

As a result the last equation should be $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n} Y_{j}^2 - n \bar Y ^2$

Comment: Sure. You mean how is this $\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2-2\bar Y (n \bar Y) + n\bar Y^2\right)$ equal to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 - \bar Y^2$ ?

Comment: yeah, I also edited my previous comment on your answer to be more clear

Comment: Oh! Oh! Oh! the $\frac{1}{n}$ in front gets rid of the factor of $n$

Comment: Note, that $\sum_{j=1}^n c = nc$ for a constant value $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Taking $c=\bar{Y}$ shows $\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j^2 -n\bar{Y}^2=\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j^2 -\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{Y}^2=\sum_{j=1}^n (Y_j^2-\bar{Y}^2)$.

Comment: Bingo! there is some cancelling I guess :-)

Comment: @user408858, yes I could have cut many of the lines there but the OP seemed pretty confused so I opted for an expanded version. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, now I am confused myself. I will try it, too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's define $c:=\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j$. As already mentioned in the comments, it holds $\sum_{j=1}c=nc$ for a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

It is easy to see, that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2&=Y_j^2-2\bar{Y}Y_j+\bar{Y}^2=Y_j^2-2cY_j+c^2\\
\end{aligned}$$

From this, one finds

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^n\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2-2c\sum_{j=1}^nY_j+\sum_{j=1}^n c^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2-2c(nc)+nc^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 -nc^2.\\
\end{aligned}$$

This implies

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2
&=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 \right) -c^2\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 \right) -\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j \right)^2.\\
\end{aligned}$$

However, it is also true, that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^n\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 -nc^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 -\sum_{j=1}^nc^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2 -\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{Y}^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j^2-\bar{Y}^2),
\end{aligned}$$

such that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left( Y_j - \bar{Y}\right)^2&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j^2-\bar{Y}^2).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Ok, but how does your answer differ from mine?

Comment: I'm sorry, but still, it's a duplicate of mine. Furthermore, the use of $c$ doesn't add anything since $\bar Y$ is already a constant.